# MySQL where first character is a number

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a dropdown:

```
<form name="alphasearch" action="ialphalist.php" method="get">
<select style='font-size:26px;height:30px;width:540px;' name='alphasearch' onchange='this.form.submit()'>
   <option value="">Select the First letter of the Business Name</option>
   <option value="REGEXP'^[0-9]'">0-9</option>
   <option value="a%">A</option>
   <option value="b%">B</option>
   <option value="c%">C</option>
```

here is a snippet from ialphalist.php:

```
list($categoriesRecords, $categoriesMetaData) = getRecords(array(
    'tableName'   => 'categories',
    'perPage'     => '5',
    'loadUploads' => false,
    'allowSearch' => true,
    'where'       => "Bus_name LIKE '$_GET[alphasearch]'",
    'orderBy'    => 'Bus_name',
```

The letters(A, B, C, etc.) display results as expected, I am trying to get it to work if the first character is a number. I thought that using the "REGEXP" statement was supposed to work, maybe I have it formatted wrong? What do I need to change to get this to work?

Comment: You can't have both `LIKE` *and* `REGEX` in the condition.

Comment: What can I use instead Ignacio?

Comment: Either one or the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:-

```
list($categoriesRecords, $categoriesMetaData) = getRecords(array(
    'tableName'   => 'categories',
    'perPage'     => '5',
    'loadUploads' => false,
    'allowSearch' => true,
    'where'       => "Bus_name REGEXP '^[a-zA-Z].*'",
    'orderBy'    => 'Bus_name',
```

**EDIT** : Specifying criteria via web page

```
$regex = "'^".$_GET[alphasearch][0]."'";
    list($categoriesRecords, $categoriesMetaData) = getRecords(array(
        'tableName'   => 'categories',
        'perPage'     => '5',
        'loadUploads' => false,
        'allowSearch' => true,
        'where'       => "Bus_name REGEXP $regex",
        'orderBy'    => 'Bus_name',
```

This would get all those bus names which starts with an alphabet(either small or upper)  .

[a-zA-Z] => ALphabet

.  => Single character (number,alphabet or whatever else)

.*  => character after first alphabet could be zero or more.

Hope it helps.

Comment: In what way does this allow the end user to specify the search criterion via web page?

Comment: Don't stop now, you're only half way to answering the question.

Comment: Yes, please, that works for the letters but what "option value" do I use in my dropdown for any record that starts with any number?

Comment: Ok. Sorry if i have misunderstood you.  If you use only [0-9] instead of REGEXP'^[0-9]' in your option value then that would be better i think. After changing it to [0-9], you can try this in your where condition:-
@dnevels

$regex = $_GET[alphasearch];
 "Bus_name  REGEXP '^".$regex.".*' OR Bus_name  LIKE '".$regex."'";

Comment: Sumit, thank you for helping me with this. Did you make a syntax error or something in your $regex statement above? I get a blank screen when I choose letter or number now.

Comment: @dnevels . I havn't tested it in php but in MySQL. And it is working in MySQL... You may debug your php code a bit.

Following queries i tried and are working :-

SELECT *FROM t1 WHERE _name  REGEXP '^A%.*' OR _name LIKE 'A%'

SELECT *FROM t1 WHERE _name  REGEXP '^[0-9].*' OR _name LIKE '[0-9]'